# C: None-Recursive function into recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I need to write a program for calculating the squares of numbers from 0 to n.i know how to do it using iteration,but how to rewrite commented function using recursion? I feel like this is a simple task and i should deal with it with no problems,but something went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0, n,m;
    printf("Enter last integer ");
    scanf_s("%d\n", &n);
    while (x < n) /* How to rewrite this function using recursion?*/
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", x*x);
        x++;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but something went wrong" --- what? Please show your efforts. In effect, you are showing us code which works but asking for debugging help in some *other* code.

Comment: Specify to which part you have to apply recursion. Calculating square and/ or printing squares from 0 to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
void function(int i, int n)
{
     if(i < n)
     {
          printf("\n%d\n", i*i);
          function(i + 1, n);
     }
     else
          return;
}
```

and then call `function(0, n);`.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am not allowed to use multiplication,but i think that i can solve this problem by myself now.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is:

```
void ipow(int x)
{
    if (x>1)
        ipow(x-1);
    printf ("%d\n",x*x);
}
```

Note: placing the print statement either before or after the recursive call prints the results in either decrasing or increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

I am rewiring your program to satisfy a recursive way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void square(int x, int n)
{
 if(x < n)
 {
      printf("\n%d\n", x*x);
      function(++x, n);
 }
 else
      return;
}


int main()
{
 int x=0, n,m;
 printf("Enter last integer ");
 scanf_s("%d\n", &n);
 square(x,n);
   _getch();
 return 0;
}
```